# Use \delimiterfactor with slash (xits)

Tags: unicode-math, delimiters

I am trying to slightly reduce the dimensions of the \slash delimiter with \delimiterfactor.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\hfrac}[2]{\left.#1\middle\fracslash#2\right.}
\[ a/b \qquad \hfrac{a}{b} \qquad \hfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \qquad x^{\hfrac{1}{2}} \qquad x^{y^{\hfrac{2}{3}}} \]

\renewcommand{\hfrac}[2]{\delimiterfactor=850\left.#1\middle\fracslash#2\right.}
\[ a/b \qquad \hfrac{a}{b} \qquad \hfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \qquad x^{\hfrac{1}{2}} \qquad x^{y^{\hfrac{2}{3}}} \]

\renewcommand{\hfrac}[2]{\delimiterfactor=800\left.#1\middle\fracslash#2\right.}
\[ a/b \qquad \hfrac{a}{b} \qquad \hfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \qquad x^{\hfrac{1}{2}} \qquad x^{y^{\hfrac{2}{3}}} \]

\end{document}
```

Here is the result.

[image: result]

Switching from 901 (default value) to 850 as no effect but switching to 800 get an huge reduction (it also looks like the delimiter is slightly too shifted down). How can I get something more smooth ? (the \delimitershortfall command seems not helping)

Comment: The slash is only available in some fixed sizes.

Comment: You may take a look a the `xfrac` package (https://ctan.org/pkg/xfrac).  It defines the `\sfrac{}{}` command.

Comment: @egreg So, no way to get a better result ? And, is it possible to use slash from another font ?

Comment: @user94293 yes, but result isn't really nice with xits fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since slash is only available in some fixed sizes (thx @egreg), the following solution using `scalerel` is not bad.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand{\hfrac}[2]{#1\scalerel{\divslash}{\vphantom{#1}#2}}
\begin{document}

\[ \hfrac{a}{b} \qquad \hfrac{\sqrt{a}}{(b+c)} \qquad \hfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \qquad x^{\hfrac{1}{2}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image: result]